# MVC5 action that can return either View(model) or json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a following problem:
I got an EDIT page, it contains some inputs and so on - nothing unusual. On submit button click I have to validate the form on server and do one of the following actions:

1. return the model if there are errors
2. return some info saying it's all good

Why? Because I need to display a bootstrap modal window when everything's ok. So what I did is (simplifying):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditData(DataViewModel model)
{
    ...
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    return Json(new { success = true, message = "all good" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What is the problem? I'm posting the form with javascript and waiting for the answer like that:

```
{
    $(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Controller/EditData",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#submitForm').serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data.success + ' ' + data.message);
            if (data.success) {
                $('#modalBody').text(data.message);
                $('#modal-window-add').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So as you can see it does display the modal window but it doesn't do anything when a model comes in. In the latter situation completely nothing happens although the response comes.

Is there any other option to solve my problem? Generally I HAVE to display that modal window on successful edit and on modal closing I need to redirect to another page - this is easy. I tried including the model inside the json but it didn't work and it seems like a lot of work to check all the fields manually and then displaying these red errors under inputs that didn't pass validation. I discussed it with my experienced friends but they don't have any MVC based solution. Any idea?

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: `console.log(data.success + ' ' + data.message);` displays any thing ? Log `data` like `console.log(data); and check whats the object returned

Comment: That's interesting but it never goes into .done function. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

**User Ajax For to do that work**

```
@{
var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "modal", OnBegin = "onAjaxBegin", OnComplete = "OnAjaxComplete", OnSuccess = "OnAjaxSuccess" };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Controler", "EditData", ajaxOptions, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
//write html here with model values
}
```

COntroller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditData(DataViewModel model)
{
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function OnAjaxSuccess()
{
show hide model popup
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it doesn't look like correct answer because when I return View(model), Your code will invoke OnAjaxSuccess function. How do I know now whether the controller editted the data or not? I need to display my modal window only when everything went fine. Or am I wrong? I'll be able to test your code in a few hours only,I'll comment again if I get to know if it works!

Comment: Use Partial View Form Your FOrm

Answer (score 0):

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) have a `dataType` option (The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.)

In `$.ajax` function you added option `dataType: "json"` that means you expected `json` back from server so you will get **only** `json` not other dataType like `xml`, `html`, `text`, `script`

**In your case** you want to return `json` or `html` depending on model is valid or not for that you can **remove `dateType` option** from `$.ajax` function, because If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).